# Template with pointer to member function => different error messages with VC++ 2017 and gcc 5.1

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I get stucked with the following code and would appreciate any suggestion

```
template <typename T, class U>
class A {
public:
    // Pointer to member function of U
    typedef void (U::*MemberPtr)(T);
    // Constructor
    Action(std::string action_name, MemberPtr func) {
        this->fPtr = func;
    } 
    // Invoke member function of U passed in constructor
    void invoke(T argument) {
        fPtr(argument); // <-- VC++ error C2064: Expression does not evaluate to a function call, ok for gcc  (Q1)
    }

private:
    MemberPtr fPtr;
```

This template above is used in class 'C'

```
class C; // forward decl

class C {
    void dummyDbl(double arg);

    Action<double, C> dblAction = Action<double, C>("x", &C::dummyDbl);
    // gcc (5.1.0 )complains: (VS 2017 is fine with that) (Q2)
    // Action<double, C>("x", &C::dummyDbl);
    //                ^
    // error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
```

My questions to the audience are

1. Why does the compiler (VC++ 2017) complain about the function call while gcc is fine with that (see Q1)? What am I missing?
2. Any ideas why gcc raises an error while VC++ is fine with the decl (Q2)?
3. Is there an opportunity *to leave out the second template parameter* but limiting the scope to member functions of a given class (e. g. an Action within class *X* must not call a member function of class *Y*)?

Thanks in advance,
Oliver

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Templates require instantiation to confirm what a compiler does or does not do with the code.  It is possible that the compiler skips the compilation of "bad" code, because the template was not instantiated.

Comment: The c'tor of class ``A`` is called ``Action``?

Comment: No, that was a typo, sorry. Ctor is A.

Comment: @Grottenolm You should edit your question and fix that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: No, the compiler should **not** skip compilation of uninstantiated template code. Templates have two-phase compilation, and the first phase happens regardless. I am being nitpicky here precisely because MSVC is known to not do proper two-phase compilation, and this question specifically asks why MSVC behaves differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
void invoke(T argument) {
    fPtr(argument); // <-- VC++ error C2064: Expression does not evaluate to a function call, ok for gcc  (Q1)
}
```

Is malformed. You need an object to call a member function, and you do not have one here. The reason why you see an error in MSVC, but not with GCC is likely due to the difference in processing template instantiation. Full code is needed to give the exact reason, but it would likely be a moot exercise - regardless of the appearances, the code is bad on any compiler and should be fixed.

The second code

```
Action<double, C> dblAction = Action<double, C>("x", &C::dummyDbl);
```

looks like a bug in gcc5, it compiles correctly in gcc6. It alaso compiles correctly in CLang since 3.4.1

This code compiles everywhere:

```
A<double, C> dblAction{"x", &C::dummyDbl};
```

Sorry, the question 3 is unclear, and the best format for SO is **one** question per post. So I suggest the question 3 is split out into separate post.

Comment: For Q3, I think OP wants something like `template <typename T>
using Action = ::Action<T, C>;` inside `class C`.